# How to change the default "Validation Error: Value is not valid" message?

Tags: java, jsf, validation, message, default-value

Below are 4 related posts I could find on Stack Overflow:

- [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9069379/1225328)
- [Validation error value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7096632/1225328)
- [Jsf : Validation error value is not valid for SelectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4566587/1225328)
- [JSF with Enum 'Validation Error: Value is not valid'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2548879/1225328)

In these posts, the posters didn't know why they had this error message. In my case, I do know why I have this error, and I would like to change the default *"Validation Error: Value is not valid"* message to let's say *"This is my message"*. How could I achieve this?

PS1: I already tried the `requiredMessage`, `validatorMessage` and `converterMessage` attributes, but none of them get called in this special case.

PS2: I'm using RichFaces 4.1.0, so the drop-down list I'm using is the `rich:select` one.

---

**Scenario:**

1. I have two entities, for example employers and employees.
2. I create the employee `employee1`.
3. I want to create the employer `employer1`, and link it to the `employee1` via a drop-down list.
4. **Before submitting the employer creation form**, I delete the `employee1` from the database.
5. Then, I submit the employer creation form: the said message appears next to the drop-down list, since the `employee1` isn't available anymore.

This behavior is the one I expected, but I just would like to change the default message to another one, more *user-friendly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply a custom converter and throw it as converter exception in `getAsObject()`.

Basically,

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Employee employee = findEmployeeInDatabase(submittedValue);

    if (employee == null) {
        throw new ConverterException("Sorry, unknown employee.");
    }
    else {
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Note that this also enables you to use `converterMessage`.

Comment: To be honest, I hoped you would have seen my question since I bet you probably had the solution `;)` This is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All stock JSF messages are in the `javax.faces` package of your JSF Distribution. The one you're looking for is with the key `javax.faces.component.UISelectone.INVALID`(or `UISelectMany`). Modify this property to get the results you want

Comment: Is there any way to put different messages depending on the drop-down list? For the example I gave, I could need *"The employee doesn't exist anymore"*, but for another drop-down list, I could need another message.

Comment: @sp00m 1. Try to avoid messing with that file too much, it's tacky design. 2. The properties file doesn't hold logic, just key-value pairs, so in theory, you can store any message string there. You have to implement a validator to then hold the logic that selects the right message based on whatever condition